# Как работать с медиафайлами в Java?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с видео, аудио - файлами в Java. Желательно привести пример исходника.

Answer (score 1):

JMF - Java Media Framework. Примеры кода здесь: [Code Samples and Apps](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-141145.html).